# Empty ComboBox in Excel Userform

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, userform

Within my UserForm_Initialize() method, I have many combo boxes and text boxes which are all uniquely named and initialized using virtually the same code.

For some reason, one combo box is always empty, and does not list any of the options I have added when clicked. Below is an example of code that successfully added options to a combo box, and the code which is not working. Note: this code is together with many other pieces of code within the same UserForm_Initialize() method.

Code that works:

```
'Empty NtwrkSrvrHD
 NtwrkSrvrHD.Clear

'Fill NtwrkSrvrHD
With NtwrkSrvrHD
     .AddItem ""
     .AddItem "Hard Drive – 300GB 10K 2.5"" SAS"
     .AddItem "Hard Drive – 600GB 10K 2.5"" SAS"
End With
```

Code that doesn't work:

```
'Empty DBHS_Ram
 DBHS_Ram.Clear

'Fill DBHS_Ram
With DBHS_Ram
     .AddItem ""
     .AddItem "RAM - 32GB for - 13ba Server Class Workstation"
     .AddItem "RAM - 128GB for - 13ba Server Class Workstation"
End With

'Set DBHS_Ram default
DBHS_Ram.Value = "RAM - 32GB for - 13ba Server Class Workstation"
```

Both combo boxes have the same properties, with the exception of the "name" and "Top"  properties.

Comment: Is there any other code messing around with it? That code works exactly as expected for me.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. 

There is a very strong possibility that you have `DBHS_Ram_Change()` event or `Userform_Activate` event where you might be accidentally clearing off the combo.

Comment: Thanks @SiddharthRout, you helped me find a rogue DBHS_Ram.clear command later on in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try the following:

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
'Code code code
    With Me
        With .DBHS_Ram
            'More code code code
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

If this fails, try using `.List` instead of `.Item`. Let us know if this helps.

Comment: There was a rogue DBHS_Ram.clear command a couple hundred lines of code later.